# Send String Data without Changing Activity(Intent)

Tags: java, android

I am trying to send the string from one Activity to Another WITHOUT changing the CURRENT ACTIVITY. This my code I used:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("getFollowerNumberData", txt);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Using this code bring me to the other activity or I do not want that. I just want to send this string without changing activity. I tried this one

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
```

But it is crashing my app. First of all it is possible to do so? If yes, how can I achieve that?

Edit: To be more clear, it works like follower and Following features in other apps or games. When you follow someone the number of the person you just followed goes up as well your Following number. Since my SignInPlayerProfile.Class(where the Following should go up to one too) is in another activity I was trying to get this information  `intent.putExtra("getFollowerNumberData, txt);` from Main Activity and display that in the SignInPlayerPlayer by using `text.setText()`. But the Problem is by using `intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);` it brings me to SignInPlayerProfile Activity which I do not like since

> I am trying to send the string from one Activity to Another WITHOUT changing the CURRENT ACTIVITY(or simpler words WIHTOUT Going to the Other Activity).

Thanks for Help.

Comment: So do you want to send an Intent to the current Activity without start it again?

Comment: "I am trying to send the string from one Activity to Another WITHOUT changing the CURRENT ACTIVITY" -- why? The other activity cannot do much with this information until it returns to the foreground anyway.

Comment: post error stack trace

Comment: If you want to save something between activities you should consider call one activity with startActivityForResult(). More info @ https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html    Also there is the Shared Preferences where you can save stuff, that is accessible from all your activities. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: post your errors, there can be too many areas of cause, do read upon start actviity for result

Comment: use a broadcast receiver. there is an ban on implicit broadcasts now, but you can follow this blog https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/04/11/android-o-implicit-broadcast-ban.html

Comment: @Fondesa Please take a look on the Edit

Comment: @CommonsWare  Please take a look on the Edit

Comment: @Remario Please take a look on the Edit

Comment: @Totoo Please take a look on the Edit

Comment: @paul_hundal Please take a look on the Edit

Comment: Since only one Activity can run at a time, you can pass datas between them via Shared Preferences like I mentionet it before. And check the Activity lifecycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an activity getting closed, according to it's life-cycle, it will be destroyed and no longer exists, when you start an activity it will be created and then it can get your data, so you can't send data to an destroyed activity which no longer exists

You can use Static Variables to communicate between activities (Classes), you can change value of a Static-Variable of an activity from another activity, but it's not a good option for data you need to be alive because Static Variables lives on Heap Memory and Heap will be freed if Android OS needs more Memory

Another way is to create a Message Handler in your first activity as a Static Variable and then send a Message to the Handler from second activity, see this example :

http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-handler-example

I suggest you using `SharedPreferences` for saving your data in first activity and load from it on second activity

**EDIT** :

According to your edit, the "Number" you want to use in another Activity as "Following" or "Followers" is just needed when the second activity is visible, you should use sharedpreferences to save the "Number" and load from it when you need it. For example before `text.settext()` method you can load the number from sharedpreferences and then pass it to `text.settext()`

You should not save your data on the variables or classes and should save them on a file like a Database or SharedPreferences then you can load them every time you want

Furthermore you can search about Activity life-cycle and see how to use life-cycle events like OnStart to load your data

Comment: SharedPreferences sound not bad too. Please take a look I have edited my question to make more clear as possible. Thanks

Comment: @AmazingPerson you should use SharedPreferences, I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Firstly please consider `startActivityForResult()` ,we can send information from one activity to another and vice-versa. As mentioned consider using shared_preferences for local in memory storage. To truly accomplish this feat in a elegant way though, do consider using obervables(rxandroid). You publish observations in one activity or fragment ,

then subscribe in another activity or fragment. I did not mentioned event bus nor otto since rxjava/rxandroid surpasses it. They act a promise context management system. Also because observable in process dependent consider using broadcast receivers, to broadcast events through out your application and external if so desired.

Comment: i would go with a reactive approach such as rxjava or rxandroid